# SQL Serverで日時ごとの件数の累積値を出力するSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Serverで下記のクエリーを作りました：

```
SELECT dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, CreationDate), 0), COUNT(*)
FROM Table
GROUP BY dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, CreationDate), 0)
```

結果は一時間ごとにその時間の新しいレコードになります：

```
12/2/14 0:00    174
12/2/14 1:00    108
12/2/14 2:00    84
12/2/14 3:00    48
12/2/14 4:00    21
```

累計をしたい場合に、どう変換すればいいですか？

目指している結果は下記です：

```
12/2/14 0:00    174
12/2/14 1:00    282
12/2/14 2:00    366
12/2/14 3:00    414
12/2/14 4:00    435
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

window関数を使うといいと思います。
SQL Fiddleにサンプルコードを載せました。

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e30e7/7

参考までにコードを転記しておきます。

```
create table some_log (
  CreationDate datetime
)

insert some_log values ('2014-12-02 00:10')
insert some_log values ('2014-12-02 00:20')
insert some_log values ('2014-12-02 00:30')
insert some_log values ('2014-12-02 01:10')
insert some_log values ('2014-12-02 02:10')
insert some_log values ('2014-12-02 02:10')

WITH count_by_hour AS
  (SELECT dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, CreationDate), 0) AS datetime,
          COUNT(*) AS cnt
   FROM some_log
   GROUP BY dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, CreationDate), 0))
SELECT datetime,
       cnt,
       SUM(cnt) over(ORDER BY datetime) AS cum_cnt
FROM count_by_hour
ORDER BY datetime
```

実行結果

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

window関数の詳しい使い方はこちらです。

http://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ms189461.aspx